# Strange bug. For loop code works fine for most values, but then appends 4 times with certain values

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame, minesweeper

I am recreating the popular game minesweeper. Bombs are hidden in a grid, and where grids do not contain bombs, contain numbers of how many (if any ) bombs are connected to the grid. In order to achieve this in python, I have created a list of list of integers. this list of list acts as a set of coordinates, the number inside is then used as a key in a dictionary which is used in pygame to display an image. for example, `if grid[i][j] = (0, 0)` would be used in a dictionary to display the image for an empty box, 50 would be used to display a bomb, 1 would be used to display the number 1 within the box.

in order to display the numbers surrounding the bombs, I have made for loop with if statements to add tuples which correspond to the coordinates. when a bomb location has `(14,x)` in the first for loop it appends `(13,x)` 4 times. and I cannot figure out why. I am most curious to find help as to what the bug is, and would be even more appreciative if someone could suggest a more 'pythonic' way of achieving this. Please see the code below.

The code runs and produces a list of tuples. It might have to be run a couple of times to produce the results.

My code:

```
import random

bomb_count = 15

def set_grid():
    grid = [[0 for x in range(30)] for x in range(15)]
    num_columns = [x for x in range(30)]
    num_rows = [x for x in range(15)]
    counter = 0

    while counter < bomb_count:
        rndnum1 = random.choice(num_rows)
        rndnum2 = random.choice(num_columns)

        grid[rndnum1][rndnum2] = 50
        counter += 1

    return grid


def set_bomb_locations(grid):
    grid_with_bombs = []
    print("grid = ", grid)

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            if grid[i][j] == 50:
                grid_with_bombs.append((i, j))

    return grid_with_bombs


def number_layout(grid_with_bombs):
    numbers_to_add_to_grid = []

    for a, b in grid_with_bombs:
        c = a + b
        print(" this is", a, b)
        if b < 29:  # only if b isnt more than 29
            c = a, b + 1
            print("if statement 1: ", numbers_to_add_to_grid)
            numbers_to_add_to_grid.append(c)
        if b > 0:  # only if b isnt 0
            c = a, b - 1
            print("if statement 2: ", numbers_to_add_to_grid)
            numbers_to_add_to_grid.append(c)
        if a > 0 and b > 0:  # only if a isnt 0 and b isnt 0
            c = a - 1, b - 1
            print("if statement 3: ", numbers_to_add_to_grid)
            numbers_to_add_to_grid.append(c)
        if a > 0:  # only if a isnt 0
            c = a - 1, b
            print("if statement 4: ", numbers_to_add_to_grid)
            numbers_to_add_to_grid.append(c)
        if a > 0 and b < 29:  # only if a isnt 0 and b isnt more than 29
            c = a - 1, b + 1  # error?
            print("if statement 5: ", numbers_to_add_to_grid)
            numbers_to_add_to_grid.append(c)
        if a < 14 and b > 0:  # only if a isnt more than 15 and b isnt 0
            c = a + 1, b - 1
            print("if statement 6: ", numbers_to_add_to_grid)
        numbers_to_add_to_grid.append(c)
        if a < 14:  # only if a isnt more than 15
            c = a + 1, b
            print("if statement 7: ", numbers_to_add_to_grid)
        numbers_to_add_to_grid.append(c)
        if a < 14 and b < 29:  # only if a isnt more than 15 and b isnt more than 29
            c = a + 1, b + 1
            print("if statement 8: ", numbers_to_add_to_grid)
        numbers_to_add_to_grid.append(c)

    for a, b in numbers_to_add_to_grid:

        if grid[a][b] != 50:
            grid[a][b] += 1

    return grid

grid = set_grid()
grid2 = set_bomb_locations(grid)
grid_with_bombs = number_layout(grid2)
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  As the posting guidelines tell you "make it easy for others to help you."  Your output has labeled `if` statements and a list of 2-tuples, with no particular explanation of where to find the error.

Comment: I suggest that you first reduce the grid size so we don't get dazzled with the quantity of data.  Second, don't tell us to run this a few times: *you* force the situation you want to show us.  Then detect the situation, halt the program, and add the deterministic output to your post.  Trace a couple of suspect variables related to the problem.  Use meaningful variable names.

Comment: Since you're not using `elif`, multiple `if` conditions can be satisfied. Is that intentional?

Comment: the if statements are intentional. because the tuple for the bomb location is used to map the surrounding coords in the form of a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

I realize these should be posted as comments, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

`[x for x in range(30)]` can be changed to `[*range(30)]`

But that can be avoided by using `random.randint()` instead of `random.choice.()`, and the `while` loop isn't necessary, you can use a `for` loop since it's a set number:

```py
from random import randint

for i in range(bomb_count):
    grid[randint(0, 30)][randint(0, 15)] = 50
```

Instead of using `len()` and `range()` to iterate through the grid, just iterate through it:

```py
#INSTEAD OF:
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            if grid[i][j] == 50:
                grid_with_bombs.append((i, j))
#USE THIS:
    for c_index, column in enumerate(grid):
        for r_index, row in enumerate(column):
            if row == 50:
                grid_with_bombs.append((c_index, r_index))
```

Comment: I would help more, but I have no clue what you're trying to achieve with the mass of `if` statements

Comment: Also, in the second suggestion I used the variable `row`.  Though this is inaccurate as it's technically a point, `row` makes it easier to understand what is represents.

Comment: Hi Elan-R thanks for your answer however some of it is incorrect. for column in grid DOES NOT return the same as for i in range in this example, the first appends tuple locations, the second does not.  also grid[randint(0,30][randint(0,15)] = 50 not as you have wrote it, however thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Oops my mistake.  I just edited it.  I changed the second code to accomplish your goal as well.

Comment: thanks very much Elan-R that works now, what about the [*range 30] ? im interested how  you would use this approach to achieve the same as grid = [[0 for x in range(30)] for x in range(15)] as [*range 30] does not produce the same thing

Comment: You forgot to put the parentheses.  `*` unpacks an iterable and `[]` generates a list.  So `[*range(30)]` unpacks the iterable `range(30)` into the list constructor.

Comment: And I'm not replacing `[0 for x in range(30)]` I'm replacing `[x for x in range(30)]`.  But if you wanted to improve `[0 for x in range(30)]`, just do `[0] * 30`.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it, by re writing the code to fit a "logic by exception" rule. to over come my problem. i simply added every tuple to a temporary list, and then removed the tuples that were not in the required parameters. I think the lesson here is, the more complex the logic, the more likely and, the harder fixing any bugs become. Below is the code that now works. sometimes a way to fix a bug, is to rewrite the logic. free to add further improvements.  on a side note, i have found a grid created this way is very useful in creating games in pygame like snake, minsweeper, tetris, etc etc, i learned this approach from someone else and is really helping me learn how useful lists are in python, feel free to use and share.

```
my code below

from random import randint
def set_grid():
grid_with_bombs = []
grid_with_bombs_and_numbers = []

# create grid with all 0
grid = [[0 for x in range(30)] for x in range(15)]

# choose 15 random locations for bombs
for i in range(bomb_count):
    grid[randint(0, 14)][randint(0, 29)] = 50

# create a list of bomb locations as tuples
for c_index, column in enumerate(grid):
    for r_index, row in enumerate(column):
        if row == 50:
            grid_with_bombs.append((c_index, r_index))

# use tuples from above to mark out any grid cell as next to a bomb
# and create a temp list of tuples with those locations
temp_tuple_list = []
for a, b in grid_with_bombs:

    c = a, b + 1
    d = a, b - 1
    e = a - 1, b - 1
    f = a - 1, b
    g = a - 1, b + 1
    h = a + 1, b - 1
    i = a + 1, b
    j = a + 1, b + 1

    temp_list = [c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]
    for i in temp_list:
        temp_tuple_list.append(i)

# now remove tuples that correspond to a grid reference that does not exist. e.g (-1,29)
for a,b in temp_tuple_list:

    c = a,b
    if a == -1 or a >= 15:
        continue
    if b == -1 or b >= 30:
        continue
    else:
        grid_with_bombs_and_numbers.append(c)


# every tuple that isnt 50( a bomb ) or 0 ( nothing ) is a number square,
# each time a tuple is in the list add 1 this will give us a value to display
for a,b in grid_with_bombs_and_numbers:
    if grid[a][b] != 50:
        grid[a][b] += 1


return grid
```